# Why is there sometimes an "e" added to a dativ noun?

Tags: dative

I.e. "Warnung vor dem Hunde"

Why is it not just "dem Hund" ?

Basicly it's a normal whom question, isn't it?

Comment: This is an old declination of _Hund_. You can use _dem Hund_, too.

Comment: but is there a rule of thumb on when this is used? i can imagine that it sounds more respektfull to someone who is reading the said sign

Comment: You may use both forms. The `e`-form is outdated and sounds a little bit strange although it's still in use on the signs.

Comment: Related: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/17381/is-it-still-considered-correct-to-append-an-e-in-old-fashioned-dative and https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/29683/im-herbst-im-herbste-reasons-to-use-the-old-dative-ending

Comment: Related: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/39211/why-is-the-dative-e-not-used-in-zu-hans-haus

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This *-e* is now archaic and almost not used except some set phrases (*zu Hause*, *in diesem Sinne*, *im Jahre so-und-so*) but this form was normal earlier.

You can read a little about it on [English Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dative_case#German) and much more on German - [Dativ-e](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dativ#Dativ-e).

Comment: Good link, thx.

Comment: Addition: The -e dative ending is still somewhat present in lyrics - "Am Brunnen vor dem Tore ..."