# Warum "Im Falle" und nicht "in der Falle"

Tags: grammatical-case

Warum nutzt man *"Im Falle eines Krieges..."* und nicht *"In der Falle eines Krieges..."* oder *"Im Fall eines Krieges..."*?

Ich meine, die Falle ist weiblich und "In der Falle..." wird der Dativ, oder?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wie von @Björn_Friedrich richtig bemerkt, handelt es sich um zwei verschiedene Wörter, "der Fall" und "die Falle".

Daß man den Dativ manchmal mit der Endung "-e" bildet, ist dem Umstand geschuldet, daß dies früher den Normalfall dargestellt hat, dessen Wegfall wir aber seit langer Zeit beobachten können. Im "normalen" Sprachgebrauch wird das Dativ-e kaum noch verwendet, in feststehenden Wendungen aber hat es sich erhalten, zum Beispiel:

> zu Hause
> im Falle [eines Falles]
> wie [etwas] im Buche steht

Diese (und weitere, ähnliche) Wendungen werden in der alltäglichen Sprache durchaus genutzt, während das Dativ-e außerhalb dieser, zum Beispiel:

> Dem Hause fehlts an Farbe.

eher altertümlich bis altertümelnd wirken. Zu Zeiten Goethes war das noch anders. Im "Faust" sagt Gretchen:

> Nach Golde drängt, am Golde hängt doch alles.

Comment: "Daß man den Dativ manchmal mit der Endung "-e" bildet, ist dem Umstand geschuldet, daß dies früher den Normalfall dargestellt hat, dessen Wegfall wir aber seit langer Zeit beobachten können." In diesen Satz hätte "dem Umstande" zum Beispiel hervorragend gepasst! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Hier handelt es sich um zwei völlig verschiedene Wörter:

- der [Fall](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Fall#2): *Umstand* oder *Angelegenheit*. Beispiel mit Dativ:

  > *Im Fall(e)* eines Krieges …
- die [Falle](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Falle): *Fangvorrichtung*. Beispiel mit Dativ:

  > Wir sitzen *in der Falle* des Gegners.

Comment: OK, aber warum hat "der Fall" manchmall ein "e" am Ende? Auch mit deinem Beispiel schreibst du "In Fall(e)", warum das (e)?

Comment: Das ist der veraltende Dativ mit -e. Kann man noch nutzen, ist aber inzwischen außerhalb von feststehenden Begriffen eher selten gebräuchlich.

Comment: You are looking at dative -e. A little bit more background: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/40750/ with further links.